# How to define a specific Css for a route and dosen't effet on another routes in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

Hi i am using nextjs and when i load a css file on a route (page) it will affect the other routes if the class name is the same i do not want to do that. i want to define a css file on a route that dose not affect another pages even if the class name is the same how can i do that?

for example i use a class with the name of ".headertop" on 2 different pages and the css is different  on pages as well when i come on one of these pages and come back to other the style in the class changes.
i want the style be different on all routes even if the class name is the same.